# Heatmap from 1D array or list, what should x-axis be?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a 1D array consisting of over 100,000 values. If I were to plot it on a scatterplot, it would pretty much just be one solid color block. So, I want to use a heatmap instead.

I saw various methods, but they either want a 2D array or have "x" and "y" values. If my 1D array values were y, what should the x-axis be? I only want to see how highly "concentrated" those values are in one area of the plot.

`plt.imshow()` requires at least a 2D array.
`plt.pcolormesh()` requires X and Y.
`plt.hexbin()` requires X and Y.
`np.histogram2d()` requires X and Y (from an example I saw).

Thank you.

Comment: How do you make a scatterplot with only one array if your x values aren't implicitly `np.arange(len(values))`? `plt.scatter` requires both x and y.

Comment: @Reti43 Ah yes, sorry. That is what I used as x. Should the x be the same, too, when using the other functions?

Comment: You can use `your_1d_array.reshape(-1,1)` (vertical) or `your_1d_array.reshape(1,-1)` (horizontal). For example `plt.imshow(your_1d_array.reshape(1,-1), aspect='auto')`.  With 100,000 values you'll inevitably have lots of values onto the same pixel.

Comment: IMVHO you are looking for an histogram

Comment: @gboffi Thanks, that's what I ended up using.